# Fatal: https://github.com/<>/<>/info/refs not valid: is it a git repository? Error while pulling from remote repo

Tags: git, github, ssh, fatal-error, git-pull

From production branch of repo I am trying to pull into production branch using following command.

```
 git pull origin production
```

I get this error:

> Fatal: https://github.com/svp19/parsec.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

I have tried `git remote show origin` but I get the same error.

My `.git/config` file content is as below

```
user@anand-Standard-PC:~/Downloads/parsec/.git$ cat config
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://github.com/svp19/parsec.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "production"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/production
[remote "originSSH"]
url = ssh://git@stash.****.net:7999/svp19/parsec.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/originSSH/*
```

How do I solve it and pull into my local repository?

Comment: At the URL https://github.com/svp19/parsec.git/info/refs I see error "*Please upgrade your git client.
GitHub.com no longer supports git over dumb-http: https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days*" The blog post is from 2011. How old are your `git` client?

Comment: I am using git 2.11.0

Comment: Hmm… good enough. Are you sure nobody removed or renamed the repository at Github, or changed password?

Comment: repository contains code for live website which I am maintaining. I am sure it is not removed or renamed.